# Does OpenLayers support geometries defined by gml:Ring

Tags: openlayers

I am trying to process some GML (3.1) that defines polygon using the following structure

```
<gml:Polygon>
  <gml:exterior>
    <gml:Ring>
      ....
    </gml:Ring>
  </gml:exterior>
</gml:Polygon>
```

but openlayers doesn't manage to parse the polygon geometry. When I step it in the debugger it looks like openlayers only expects a `<gml:LinearRing>` after a `<gml:exterior>` however I can find places online where the above seems to be valid GML (e.g. http://erouault.blogspot.com/2014/04/gml-madness.html)

Does openlayers only handle polygons defined using linear rings?

Comment: I think OpenLayers uses this simple feature schema http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.1.1/profiles/gmlsfProfile/1.0.0/gmlsf.xsd There's no gml:Ring and LineString/LinearRing use only gml:posList (gml:pos is only used for Point)

Comment: Thanks, bit confusing. The ol.format.GML3 class seems to have support for LinearRing?

Comment: Yes, Polygons with LinearRing where the coordinates are in a posList are supported.